# Meaning of "less interesting student"

Tags: word-meaning

What does this sentence mean?

> *He is a  less interesting student than his brother.*

Answer (score 2):

It would depend on context, of course. It might be that he is easy to teach, less challenging (if the teacher finds this soft of thing interesting) or he is too slow, too quiet, too "..anything.." - whatever makes this person less interesting to teach for that particular teacher.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say Peter is Paul's brother
It means Paul is a **student** and **does not command as much attention** or doesn't **capture one's imagination as much** as Peter

How this happens is dependent on what **interesting** is defined as, for example

> knowledge
>   eloquence
>   sense of humour
>   thought process
>   questioning
>   personality
>   etc.

the criteria would probably be something **based on being a student** since reference is made to being a student. The observers, those who find Paul interesting or not, could be **any audience**: fellow students, teachers, the general public.

It **does not mean** Paul is **less interested in studying** than Peter is

Answer (score 0):

In this sentence, we are talking about a student who is not smart, is dumb and cannot answer most of the questions asked to him in class. It is difficult for teachers to make him understand most of the things. On the other hand, we are talking about his brother who is smart, brilliant and can answer most of the questions asked to him in the class. It is very easy for teachers to make him understand most of the things.

Comment: I think you're reading way more into the sentence than is actually there.